# build application with microsoft api

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I studying machine learning. I am building an application with azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face and I have a problem as picture below(APIErrorException: (404) Resource not found). how can i fix it? Thanks and sorry because my english very bad.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbeaO.png)

```
    APIErrorException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-889e8e1c61a7> in <module>()
      1 single_face_image_url = 'https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTQ1MzAyNzYzOTgxNTE0NTEz/john-f-kennedy---mini-biography.jpg'
      2 single_image_name = os.path.basename(single_face_image_url)
----> 3 detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(url=single_face_image_url)
      4 if not detected_faces:
      5     raise Exception('No face detected from image {}'.format(single_image_name))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/face/operations/_face_operations.py in detect_with_url(self, url, return_face_id, return_face_landmarks, return_face_attributes, recognition_model, return_recognition_model, detection_model, custom_headers, raw, **operation_config)
    547 
    548         if response.status_code not in [200]:
--> 549             raise models.APIErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
    550 
    551         deserialized = None

APIErrorException: (404) Resource not found
```

Comment: can you please copy and paste the error, instead of screenshoting it

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed the trailing slash and at the end of endpoint like below;

```
EndPoint:https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0;
```

Try changing it to :

```
Modified : EndPoint:https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/;
```

additional reference;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/python-sdk
https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-iOS/issues/37

Hope it helps.